# youtube-dl gives errors: "command not found"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, homebrew, path

I installed youtube-dl successfully via homebrew but cannot seem to invoke the program at all.

Here are the commands I tried:

```
> man youtube-dl
No manual entry for youtube-dl
> type -a youtube-dl
-bash: type: youtube-dl: not found
> man -aw youtube-dl
No manual entry for youtube-dl
```

My PATH looks as follows:

```
> echo $PATH    
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

When I try to list installed brew packages, I get:

```
brew list
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Comment: What is your $PATH and where is youtube-dl and how exactly did you install it?

Comment: tbh, I'd just use JDownloader instead ;) No faff, no command line to grok, copy link, [no need to even paste it will capture the URL], decide whether you want the movie, soundtrack, subs, poster frame, etc. Hit go.

Comment: What's the output of running `type -a youtube-dl` and `man -aw youtube-dl` command lines?

Comment: Post is updated.

Comment: @H3R3T1K Please share the output of running `echo $PATH` and `brew list`

Comment: Included the outputs.

Comment: Are you on a machine with a Apple Silicon or an Intel CPU?

Comment: I'm on Apple Silicon.

Comment: I'm confused. How did you install using `brew` while at the same time `brew list` returns `brew: command not found`?

Comment: I honestly have no clue myself. I installed homebrew in order to get access to smartmontools to check SSD life of my refurbished Mac Mini which worked. I used this guide: https://www.macworld.com/article/334283/how-to-m1-intel-mac-ssd-health-terminal-smartmontools.html

Comment: Oh and it's definitely installed since I just installed cscreen via: brew install --cask cscreen... I had to change the default shell to bash tho.

Answer (score 1):

Your homebrew setup is broken. Can you reinstall it and then run brew doctor?

Then you will test the YouTube-dl and possibly reinstall that.

Most of the time you don’t need to uninstall `brew` but the output of `/opt/homebrew/bin/brew doctor` will tell us what’s up. Yours is in “opt” since you’re on M1 (I hope).

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/36660313/475228
- https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-homebrew

Comment: I installed homebrew via this guide bc I needed to check SSD health of my refurbished Mac Mini: https://www.macworld.com/article/334283/how-to-m1-intel-mac-ssd-health-terminal-smartmontools.html It worked fine. /opt/homebrew/bin/brew doctor returns: Homebrew's "bin" was not found in your PATH.
Consider setting your PATH for example like so:
  echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.profile

Comment: It's not broken, I just had to change shell from zsh to bash: chsh -s /bin/bash Everything works now.

Comment: Nice - it works of course in both shells,  but you have to do the setup for the second one if you don’t want to switch back to `bash`. Glad it is sorted @H3R3T1K

Comment: Could you explain this to me? How do I make it work in zsh? Is there any advantages or disadvantages to using one or the other?